Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at myfunction (scriptExtra.js:9:26)
In the title the error i get, this is the code, how can avoid the error, by the way the script works well even with the error
if(window.addEventListener){
window.addEventListener("message", myfunction, false);
}else{
window.attachEvent("onmessage", myfunction);
}

function myfunction(event) {
    if (event.data !== 'null') {
        dataJSONLocator = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (typeof dataJSONLocator == 'object' && dataJSONLocator.tntMessage !== undefined) {
                if (dataJSONLocator.tntMessage) {
                    console.log(dataJSONLocator);
                    document.getElementsByName( "address1" )[0].value = dataJSONLocator.name + " " + dataJSONLocator.address;
                    document.getElementsByName( "city" )[0].value = dataJSONLocator.city;
                    document.getElementsByName( "id_state" )[0].value = dataJSONLocator.prov;
                    document.getElementsByName( "postcode" )[0].value = dataJSONLocator.cap;
            }   }
    }
}


JSON.parse() is expecting a string, but event.data is an Object.

ok, thanks, how can i avoid this error?? i have to change JSON.parse()??

It depends; what exactly are you trying to do with event.data? Why not just dataJSONLocator = event.data?

In some cases event.data is an Object, but JSON.Parse method expects string value to be able to parse it. That's how JSON works.
I would look into this line of code if (event.data !== 'null') { and check also if it's a string.
Something like:
if (event.data !== 'null' && typeof event.data === 'string') {
